# Parsing an URL without a path but with a slash in the query

Tags: php, url

I have problems parsing an URL than doesn't have a path but has a slash in the query. For example: `http://example.com?q=a/b`

I'm aware that such an URL is most likely invalid (*) - it requires at least a slash as the path like this: `http://example.com/?q=a/b`.

All browsers in which I tried such an URL in, correct the URL automatically. And that is basically what I want to reproduce: Identify and correct such an URL.

Using `parse_url` however produces:

```
var_dump( parse_url('http://example.com?q=a/b') );

array(3) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(15) "example.com?q=a"
  ["path"]=>
  string(2) "/b"
}
```

While with an URL without a slash in the query it works fine:

```
var_dump( parse_url('http://example.com?q=ab') );

array(3) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(11) "example.com"
  ["query"]=>
  string(4) "q=ab"
}
```

All external libraries I tried ([Jwage\Purl](https://github.com/jwage/purl), [League\Url](http://url.thephpleague.com/3.0/), [Sabre\Uri](http://sabre.io/uri/)) basically do the same thing, which surprises me a bit.

Why do (all?) browsers get it "right", while (all?) PHP libraries get it "wrong"?

Other than trying to catch these cases with a regular expression before parsing the URL (which may be unreliable - that's why I want to use a library in the first place), what alternatives do I have?

(*) I consulted three sources: [RFC 1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), [WHATWG URL Standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/) and they all three disagree on what is considered valid.

Comment: There is a reported bug discussing this issue: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54369

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you still want to apply a regular expression, the following should generate the URL you are looking for:

```
$url=pcre_replace('/([^/]+:\/\/[^/]+)\?/', '$1/?',$url);
```

It requires for the URL to start with a protocol name of at least one character followed by "://", a domain name of at least one character ("localhost" would be acceptable too). After that it will insert  '/' before a '?', but only if there is no further '/' before the '?'.

Comment: The regular expression is not really the problem (except I don't want false positives). I'll be using: `preg_match("~^(https?://(?:[a-z0-9-]+\.)*[a-z0-9-]+(?::\d+)?)(\?.*)~", ...)`

Comment: OK, that will probably do the trick! My solution was intended as a preconditioning of the string before it is parsed using `parse_url()` ...

Answer (score -1):

The WHATWG URL Standard most closely approximates what browsers implement. Other software has not quite aligned yet, though for PHP https://phppackages.org/p/esperecyan/url might work. (Not tried.)